# how to avoid system.limitexception too many soql queries 101 in apex class

Tags: apex, map

when I am trying to deploy the component then I was getting this error like system.limitexception too many soql queries 101,how to avoid this please help me any one,thanks adavance.
I am getting error from this below code.

```
 Map<Id, Profit_Center__c> idToPC = new Map<Id, Profit_Center__c>(
            [SELECT Id, shortname_GBU__c, shortname_country__c
             FROM Profit_Center__c
             WHERE Id IN :pcIds]
        );
```

Comment: soql query limit exception is runtime exception and could be thrown only on code execution. Looks like this happens in test execution. There is no problems with code snipped that you posted. You need to re-factor your code/tests, make it bulkify. Maybe you have somewhere soql in loop

Comment: Thank you very much @OleksandrBerehovskyi ,I was saw  in my code ,But I did not found any soql in loop, shall I post my overal code ?

Comment: Yes, please. Post whole code

Comment: Here Not posting question @OleksandrBerehovskyi ,could you please look into answer post.

Comment: If you'd like help from the community, you need to post the whole trigger method.  These LimitException issues could be coming from the trigger itself, or from other part of the system (setting off other triggers with record changes, issues with data in your Unit tests, etc)